# I have three flags in OptionParser but it only gives access to two of them

Tags: ruby, optionparser

I am building a CLI gem with Ruby and I'm using OptionParser to add flags with arguments. Whenever one flag is called with an argument a function get's called.
I have three flags. My problem is, when I run the `-h` command to see the options(flags) available to use, it only shows three of them (skipping the middle one) and even if I try to use that flag, (that is not listed in help) it runs the code of the last flag.
Here is my code for the flags:

```
def city_weather
      options = {}
      OptionParser.new do |opts|
        opts.banner = "Welcome to El Tiempo! \n Usage: cli [options]"

        opts.on('-today', 'Get today\'s weather') do |today|
          options[:today] = today
          weather_today(ARGV.first)
        end

        opts.on('-av_max', 'Get this week\'s average maximum temperature') do |av_max|
          options[:av_max] = av_max
          week_average_max(ARGV.first)
        end

        opts.on('-av_min', 'Get this week\'s average minimum temperature') do |av_min|
          options[:av_min] = av_min
          week_average_min(ARGV.first)
        end
      end.parse!

      ARGV.first
    end
```

It is the `-av_max` flag that does not work.
When I run `-av_max` the `week_average_min(ARGV.first)` get's executed.

When I run the `-h` command here is what it shows:

```
Welcome to El Tiempo! 
Usage: cli [options]
    -today                           Get today's weather
    -av_min                          Get this week's average minimum temperature
```

My question is, is it possible to have three flags with OptionParser? If so, how could I make this middle flat work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another dash for long arguments:

```rb
opts.on('--av_min', 'Get this week\'s average minimum temperature') do |av_min|
  options[:av_min] = av_min
  week_average_min(ARGV.first)
end
```